# Problema ao selecionar mês com chart.js

Tags: php, sql, gráfico, chartjs

Olá, estou tendo um problema, talvez não esteja fazendo corretamente, mas, vamos lá!

Eu utilizo um gráfico com chart.js, consegui trazer os dados do sql do mês desejado normalmente, ele está comunicando e puxando os dados que eu quero.

O meu problema é o seguinte, preciso fazer com que estes dados apareça no mês correto, tenho as labels com os meses e preciso que cada mês receba seu valor. Neste caso, estou pegando os dados do mês 04, porém não consigo fazer com que estes dados apareça na label "Abr"...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
            <canvas class="line-chart"></canvas>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('document').ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "chart.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            // for (var i in data) {
            //     console.log(data[i].vendas)
            // }
            var nomearray = [];
            var idarray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                nomearray.push(data[i].data_vistoria);
                idarray.push(data[i].cpf);


            }

            grafico(nomearray,idarray);

        }
    });

})



    </script>

        <script>
        function grafico(cpf,data_vistoria) {
          var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("line-chart");

          // Type, Data e o options
          var chartGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai","Jun","Jul","Ago","Set","Out","Nov","Dez"],
                datasets:[
              {
                    label:"TAXA DE VISTORIAS - 2019",
                    data: data_vistoria,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '69baf0',
                    backgroundColor:'rgba(105,186,240,0.55)',

               },

                ]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display:true,
                    fontSite:29,
                    text:"RELATÓRIO DE VISTORIAS ANUAL"
                },
                labels: {
                    fontStyle: "bold"
                }
            }

          });


        } 

        </script>
```

Aqui segue o código do arquivo que comunica com o banco de dados e a query que estou utilizando atualmente:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mkwebd86_sistema;port=3306;charset=utf8', 'mkwebd86_mkpdf', 'Enigma123');

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cpf FROM clientes WHERE MONTH(data_vistoria) = '4'";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute();


while($results = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $result[] = $results;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tira o filtro pra puxar apenas o mês 4 e deixa ele puxar normal. Do jeito que seu código está feito ele está retornando apenas um resultado, mas apesar de ser o COUNT do mês 4, ele está preenchendo na primeira label, que é janeiro, já que puxa só um...